# Dropdown menu full width but content inside limited to 1000 pixels wide

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've recently updated our websites dropdown menu to include more results but id like the contents of the dropdown to only occupy the width of our page.

[image: This is what it currently looks like...]

[image: This is what im trying to achieve...]

I've tried playing around with the style

```
.menu > ul > li > ul {
```

The whole dropdown gets smaller instead of just the content, with what basic coding skills i have, im more use to working with divs, div within a div then center it but that just breaks everything. i think i need to somehow wrap the `<li></li>` in another container and make that control the inner content width??

Can anyone help me out, i've added the code below so you can see how the dropdown is setup.

```js
          $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
          $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
          $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
            if ($(window).width() > 943) {
              $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          });
          $(".menu > ul > li").click(function() {
            if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
              $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
            }
          });
```

```css
.mainMenuMulti {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #C50132 !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
.mainMenuOption {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
  }
  .mainMenuSale {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #C50132;
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  .mainMenuClearance {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    background-color: #CCFF00;
  }
  
  .mainMenuOption:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .mainMenuSale:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #DA0137 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .mainMenuMulti:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333333 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .mainMenuClearance:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #C4F400 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  
  .menu {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .menu img {
      max-width: 100%;
  }
  .menu_heading {
      padding: 5px 10px 10px 0px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #00CC00;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
      width: 95%;
  }
  .menu_float_1{
      width: 95%;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .menu_float_2{
      width: 49%;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .menu_float_3{
      width: 33%;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .menu-dropdown-icon::before {
    content: "\f489";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 0.7em 1.2em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
  .menu > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  /*  position: relative;*/
    /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
    box-sizing: border-box;
        clear: right;
        text-align: center;
  }
  .menu > ul::before,
  .menu > ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  .menu > ul::after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .menu > ul > li {
  /*  float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu > ul > li:not(:last-child) {
     margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .menu > ul > li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
  }
  .menu > ul > li:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
    }
  .menu > ul > li > ul::before,
  .menu > ul > li > ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul::after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    background: none;
    float: left;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li a {
    color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.8);
    padding: 0.2em 0;
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{
      color: #00CC00;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul::before,
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul::after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
    width: 300px;
    left: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headerNavigation" class="hide" style="min-width: 680px;">
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#" class="mainMenuMulti"><div>Multibuy</div></a></li>
            <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/beds" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Beds &amp; Mattresses</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Mattresses by Size</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=small-single" class="mm-listitem__text">Small Single mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=single" class="mm-listitem__text">Single mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=small-double" class="mm-listitem__text">Small Double mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=double" class="mm-listitem__text">Double mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=king" class="mm-listitem__text">Kingsize mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=super-king" class="mm-listitem__text">Super King mattresses</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div class="menu_heading">Mattresses by Type</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?m=Natural" class="mm-listitem__text">Natural mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?k=Seasonal-Turn" class="mm-listitem__text">Seasonal Turn mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?t=Pocket-Sprung" class="mm-listitem__text">Pocket Sprung mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?k=Non-Turn" class="mm-listitem__text">Non-Turn mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?m=Foam" class="mm-listitem__text">Foam mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all mattresses</b></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div class="menu_heading">Beds &amp; Bed Frames</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/build-a-bed/" style="color:#00CC00"><b>Build a Bed Online</b></a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/divan-beds/" class="mm-listitem__text">Divan Beds</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/divan-bases/" class="mm-listitem__text">Divan Bases</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/bedsteads/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bed Frames</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/headboards/" class="mm-listitem__text">Headboards</a></li>
<li><a href="/p/protect-a-bed-cotton-mattress-protector/1568830" class="mm-listitem__text">Mattress Protectors</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Beds" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Bedroom</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Type</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/bedside-cabinets/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bedside Cabinets</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/bedsteads/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bedsteads</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/chest-of-drawers/" class="mm-listitem__text">Chest of Drawers</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/dressing-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Dressing Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/headboards/" class="mm-listitem__text">Headboards</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/wardrobes/" class="mm-listitem__text">Wardrobes</a></div>
                                                   
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Range</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/ardennes" class="mm-listitem__text">Ardennes</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/ashford" class="mm-listitem__text">Ashford</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/charlton" class="mm-listitem__text">Charlton</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/geneva" class="mm-listitem__text">Geneva</a></div>
                                                   
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all bedroom collections</b></a></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Fitted Bedroom Furniture</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/locano" class="mm-listitem__text">Locano</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/locano-touch" class="mm-listitem__text">Locano Touch</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/midsomer" class="mm-listitem__text">Midsomer</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/shenaya" class="mm-listitem__text">Shenaya</a></div>
                                                   
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/fitted-bedroom-furniture" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all fitted bedroom collections</b></a></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Bedroom" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Dining</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Type</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/chairs/" class="mm-listitem__text">Chairs</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Dining Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dressers/" class="mm-listitem__text">Dressers</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/sideboards/" class="mm-listitem__text">Sideboards</a></div>
                                                   
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div class="menu_heading">Dining Tables</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?m=Oak" class="mm-listitem__text">Oak tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?k=Extending" class="mm-listitem__text">Extending tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?t=Round" class="mm-listitem__text">Round tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?t=Rectangular" class="mm-listitem__text">Rectangular tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?m=Sintered-stone" class="mm-listitem__text">Stone tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all dining tables</b></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Range</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/ardennes" class="mm-listitem__text">Ardennes</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/baltic" class="mm-listitem__text">Baltic</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/banbury" class="mm-listitem__text">Banbury</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/chateaux" class="mm-listitem__text">Chateaux</a></div>
                                                   
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all dining collections</b></a></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Dining" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Living</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
          <li style="width:75%">
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Type</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/bookcases/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bookcases</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/coffee-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Coffee Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/console-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Console Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/display-cabinets/" class="mm-listitem__text">Display Cabinets</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/lamp-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Lamp Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/mirrors/" class="mm-listitem__text">Mirrors</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/nest-of-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Nest of Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/office/" class="mm-listitem__text">Office</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/tv-cabinets/" class="mm-listitem__text">TV Cabinets</a></div>
                                                   
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Occasional" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/c/clearance" class="text14 mainMenuClearance"><div>Clearance</div></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Maybe if you set a class to the ul with display none and give it a left and right padding or margin dépends on how you need it

Answer (score 1):

In `.menu > ul > li > ul` add:

1. `max-width: 1000px;` - to limit its width when there is more than needed.
2. `right: 0;` - to stretch it to the opposite side and ensure it is horizontally centered with auto margins.

```js
          $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
          $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
          $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
            if ($(window).width() > 943) {
              $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          });
          $(".menu > ul > li").click(function() {
            if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
              $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
            }
          });
```

```css
.mainMenuMulti {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #C50132 !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
.mainMenuOption {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
  }
  .mainMenuSale {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #C50132;
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  .mainMenuClearance {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    background-color: #CCFF00;
  }
  
  .mainMenuOption:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .mainMenuSale:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #DA0137 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .mainMenuMulti:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333333 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .mainMenuClearance:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #C4F400 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  
  .menu {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .menu img {
      max-width: 100%;
  }
  .menu_heading {
      padding: 5px 10px 10px 0px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #00CC00;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
      width: 95%;
  }
  .menu_float_1{
      width: 95%;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .menu_float_2{
      width: 49%;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .menu_float_3{
      width: 33%;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .menu-dropdown-icon::before {
    content: "\f489";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 0.7em 1.2em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
  .menu > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  /*  position: relative;*/
    /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
    box-sizing: border-box;
        clear: right;
        text-align: center;
  }
  .menu > ul::before,
  .menu > ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  .menu > ul::after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .menu > ul > li {
  /*  float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu > ul > li:not(:last-child) {
     margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .menu > ul > li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
  }
  .menu > ul > li:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 1000px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
    }
  .menu > ul > li > ul::before,
  .menu > ul > li > ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul::after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    background: none;
    float: left;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li a {
    color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.8);
    padding: 0.2em 0;
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{
      color: #00CC00;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul::before,
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul::after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
    width: 300px;
    left: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headerNavigation" class="hide" style="min-width: 680px;">
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#" class="mainMenuMulti"><div>Multibuy</div></a></li>
            <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/beds" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Beds &amp; Mattresses</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Mattresses by Size</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=small-single" class="mm-listitem__text">Small Single mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=single" class="mm-listitem__text">Single mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=small-double" class="mm-listitem__text">Small Double mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=double" class="mm-listitem__text">Double mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=king" class="mm-listitem__text">Kingsize mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?size=super-king" class="mm-listitem__text">Super King mattresses</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div class="menu_heading">Mattresses by Type</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?m=Natural" class="mm-listitem__text">Natural mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?k=Seasonal-Turn" class="mm-listitem__text">Seasonal Turn mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?t=Pocket-Sprung" class="mm-listitem__text">Pocket Sprung mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?k=Non-Turn" class="mm-listitem__text">Non-Turn mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/?m=Foam" class="mm-listitem__text">Foam mattresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/mattresses/" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all mattresses</b></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div class="menu_heading">Beds &amp; Bed Frames</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/build-a-bed/" style="color:#00CC00"><b>Build a Bed Online</b></a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/divan-beds/" class="mm-listitem__text">Divan Beds</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/beds/divan-bases/" class="mm-listitem__text">Divan Bases</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/bedsteads/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bed Frames</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/headboards/" class="mm-listitem__text">Headboards</a></li>
<li><a href="/p/protect-a-bed-cotton-mattress-protector/1568830" class="mm-listitem__text">Mattress Protectors</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Beds" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Bedroom</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Type</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/bedside-cabinets/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bedside Cabinets</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/bedsteads/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bedsteads</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/chest-of-drawers/" class="mm-listitem__text">Chest of Drawers</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/dressing-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Dressing Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/headboards/" class="mm-listitem__text">Headboards</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture/wardrobes/" class="mm-listitem__text">Wardrobes</a></div>
                                                   
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Range</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/ardennes" class="mm-listitem__text">Ardennes</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/ashford" class="mm-listitem__text">Ashford</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/charlton" class="mm-listitem__text">Charlton</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/bedroom-furniture/geneva" class="mm-listitem__text">Geneva</a></div>
                                                   
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/bedroom-furniture" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all bedroom collections</b></a></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Fitted Bedroom Furniture</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/locano" class="mm-listitem__text">Locano</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/locano-touch" class="mm-listitem__text">Locano Touch</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/midsomer" class="mm-listitem__text">Midsomer</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/fitted-bedroom-furniture/shenaya" class="mm-listitem__text">Shenaya</a></div>
                                                   
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/fitted-bedroom-furniture" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all fitted bedroom collections</b></a></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Bedroom" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Dining</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Type</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/chairs/" class="mm-listitem__text">Chairs</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Dining Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dressers/" class="mm-listitem__text">Dressers</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/sideboards/" class="mm-listitem__text">Sideboards</a></div>
                                                   
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div class="menu_heading">Dining Tables</div>

            <ul>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?m=Oak" class="mm-listitem__text">Oak tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?k=Extending" class="mm-listitem__text">Extending tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?t=Round" class="mm-listitem__text">Round tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?t=Rectangular" class="mm-listitem__text">Rectangular tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/?m=Sintered-stone" class="mm-listitem__text">Stone tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture/dining-tables/" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all dining tables</b></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Range</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/ardennes" class="mm-listitem__text">Ardennes</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/baltic" class="mm-listitem__text">Baltic</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/banbury" class="mm-listitem__text">Banbury</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/r/dining-room-furniture/chateaux" class="mm-listitem__text">Chateaux</a></div>
                                                   
<div class="menu_float_1"><a href="/c/dining-room-furniture" style="color:#00CC00"><b>View all dining collections</b></a></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Dining" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown-icon"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture" class="text14 mainMenuOption"><div>Living</div></a>
        <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
          <li style="width:75%">
          <div class="menu_heading">Browse by Type</div>
            <ul>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/bookcases/" class="mm-listitem__text">Bookcases</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/coffee-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Coffee Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/console-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Console Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/display-cabinets/" class="mm-listitem__text">Display Cabinets</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/lamp-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Lamp Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/mirrors/" class="mm-listitem__text">Mirrors</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/nest-of-tables/" class="mm-listitem__text">Nest of Tables</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/office/" class="mm-listitem__text">Office</a></div>
<div class="menu_float_3"><a href="/c/occasional-furniture/tv-cabinets/" class="mm-listitem__text">TV Cabinets</a></div>
                                                   
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://placehold.co/300x300.png" alt="Occasional" width="300"></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/c/clearance" class="text14 mainMenuClearance"><div>Clearance</div></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div></div>
```